# Errors With Following Socket.io Chat-Example

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cloud9-ide

I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm using Cloud9 to setup my Node.js enviroment. I'm new to both C9 and Node.js.

I'm experimenting with Ranviermud, a Node.js powered MUD. I have it setup and working. Now I'm trying to create a node based client for using the MUD instead of telnet, like http://www.phudbase.com/ , a PHP based client.

So I thought I would try Socket.io. I followed the Socket.io chat example to the letter, but it's not working. I keep getting this error in the Chrome console: 404 not found - https://ranviermud-xarcell.c9.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441138342957-? where the ? is a different number every second.

Socket.io documentation is here: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Just because that url is showing up in your console doesn't mean it's "not working," unless the HTTP status code response to those requests is 4xx or 5xx. Otherwise it *is* working, it's just using long polling (yet) instead of websockets.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? A code snippet where you're trying to connect to, and some more error logging on the server side?

Comment: @mscdex it doesn't appear to be working like the example provided. When I type into the submit field nothing happens.